# How to enable sorting with sonata_type_model?

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I am working on a Symfony 3.3 project that uses Sonata. I have created two entities: Question and QuestionGallery. I am using a many-to-many relationship and sonata_type_model to allow users to nest a set of Questions within each Question Gallery. My formMapper->add() call looks like this:

```
    $formMapper
        ->add('name')
        ->add('visible')
        ->add(
            'questions',
            'sonata_type_model',
            ['expanded' => false, 'by_reference' => true, 'multiple' => true, 'required' => false]
        )
    ;
```

So far so good. Now I want to allow users to reorder the Question objects in an arbitrary order of their choosing. That's where I run into a problem: Even when I remove an item from the middle of the list and re-append it at the end, it reverts to being in the middle when I save the QuestionGallery. I believe the Questions are being ordered by ID, in other words.

In the short term, I have simple added a "rank" field the Question entity, which works well enough. **But I am curious: Is there a built-in way to allow arbitrary reordering without introducing an extra field that users must manually fill out?** (Bonus karma if you know of a way that allows users to drag and drop the entities.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use doctrine mapping with annotation:

```
/**
..ect..
*@ORM\OrderBy({"ranking" = "ASC"})
*/
protected $questions;
```

And in your Admin:

```
$formMapper
    ->add(
        'questions',
        'sonata_type_collection',
        [
            'expanded' => false,
            'by_reference' => true,
            'multiple' => true,
            'required' => false
        ],
        [
            'edit' => 'inline',
            'inline' => 'table',
            'sortable' => 'ranking',
            'order' => 'ASC'
        ]
    )
;
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the 'order' => 'ASC' in Admin is required. Because the final sorting you do above with the @ORM\OrderBy({"ranking" = "ASC"}). In my case it works only with the sortable => fieldname in Admin class.